# Using StreamSocket() mrthod of Scapy to send ECN enabled TCP packets

Tags: tcp, congestion

I am trying to understand how ECN flag affects TCP congestion window of sender (snd_cwnd parameter in linux).

To do so,  I used scapy to generate the desired packet on HostA directed to HostB as sr(IP(src='a.a.a.a',dst='b.b.b.b')/TCP(flags=0x050)).

This  did trigger hostA to send a  tcp ecn enabled packet to hostB, but since scapy works in user space and not particularly with Linux Kernel TCP I could not extract the the congestion window parameters .
I then used StraemSocket() module of scapy to tie scapy  connection to linux TCP socket.
Hosta = server(a.a.a.a), HostB =client(b.b.b.b)

code as below:
server:

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket()
serversocket.bind(("a.a.a.a",9876))
serversocket.listen(1)
sc,sockname = serversocket.accept()
serverstream=StreamSocket(sc)
serverstream.sr(IP(src='a.a.a.a',dst='b.b.b.b')/TCP(flags=0x050))
```

client:

```
from scpay.all import *
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket()
clientsocket.connect(("a.a.a.a",9876))
clientstream = StreamSocket(clientsocket)
clientstream.sr(IP(src="b.b.b.b",dst="a.a.a.a")/TCP(flags="S"))
```

as can be seen from below snapshot, 3 way handshake with ecn and cwd flags is successful( I have enabled ecn on the hosts and all intermediate routers). but wireshark just doesn’t capture the ecn flagged packet sent by server.I am not sure if the server sent the packet at all and I am really at the end of my thoughts here.

[image: missing ecn enabled tcp packet]

Comment: Was there network congestion which the router detected and flagged in the packet header? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: nope. I am trying to simulate the senders response by triggering a TCP with ecn flag enabled. Understandably , the intermediate routers mark the IP headers while transmitting the packets. But what I am trying to achieve is to observe how the sender reacts after receiving an congestion feedback. Thank You.

Comment: Are you sending a TCP control packet marked with congestion?

Comment: Yes. I am doing that using scapy.

Comment: Typically, a host doesn't respond to control packets marked with congestion, only to data packets marked with congestion. You want the two ECN bits set to ones to indicate that congestion was encountered on a data packet from the sender to the receiver.

Comment: I tried using html payload. Its almost the same. The client sent a HTML GET but the packet seems to have malformed, so the server just did not response. But thanks for the heads up. Also , As I understand the two flags you are refering to are ECN and CWR flags in the TCP header and not the Diff Serv flags of ECT and CE in IP .. right?

Comment: The ECN bits set to show congestion is experienced are in the IP header, but the CWR bit is in the TCP header. The ECN bits would be set on a packet in the stream toward the client (usually by a router which doesn't get involved with TCP), and the client will respond until it receives a packet with the CWR bit set in the TCP header.

Comment: Hmm. That was what I understood, but did not realise that CWR flag sets to be up as well. I think I will give a go with some html data and update the thread. ALso, apart from socket options, is there anywhere else I can get the vlaue of congestion window, I know its actually snd_cwnd paramter in tcp.o of linux but thats in kernel space.

Comment: The packets containing the TCP segments should pass through Wireshark, so you should be able to read anything in the TCP headers.

Comment: Also, You didn't show anything where you are setting the two ECN bits of the IP header in anything being sent. Are you really doing that? There is a difference between enabling ECN and marking an IP packet as congested.

Comment: Hi Ron, the scenario I am trying to replicate is the feedback mechanism in case of congestion. Hence I did not focus on the routers marking the IP headers for congestion. Instead, I have used scapy to create packets with congestion bits marked and sent as feedback.

Comment: The client, sending responding to an EC notification, will be the one to indicate that the window needs to shrink. A better test is to have the server send traffic with the ECN bits set in the IP header and observe the response of the client when TCP on the client automatically sets the IP and TCP headers to respond to the congestion notification. That will show you what changes the client makes in response, and you can also observe what the server does in response to the client's notification, too. You are probably configuring the client response incorrectly, let the client do it.

Comment: Hi Ron, That does seem like a valid test. If I understand well- instead of testing just the feedback mechanism, you are implying that I test the complete flow of events. right from setting off the congestion bits in IP layer and letting the reciever by itself set the congestion feedback bits in TCP.I will give it a go.

Comment: I originally assumed that is what you were doing.

Comment: @ Ron, I am unable to +1 your comment, but thanks for the guidance-I think now I have new information to conduct my tests more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `StreamSocket`, the packets sent are sent over the TCP connection. In Scapy notation, when you type `serverstream.sr(IP(src='a.a.a.a',dst='b.b.b.b')/TCP(flags=0x050))` (BTW, you can replace `flags=0x050` by `flags="AE"`), it will result in sending a packet like:

```
IP(src="a.a.a.a", dst="b.b.b.b") / TCP(flags="PA") / \
    IP(src="a.a.a.a", dst="b.b.b.b")/TCP(flags="AE")
```

The first `IP()/TCP()` layers are not under Scapy's control, but under the server's network stack control (e.g., you cannot change the flags there with Scapy).

The second `IP()/TCP()` layers, converted as an `str()` object, are the packet crafted by Scapy (so you have a total control over it). On the network, and for Wireshark, the packet is only raw data transported over TCP. You can guess that the fourth and sixth packets shown on your screenshot are `IP()/TCP()/IP()/TCP()` thanks to the length of the data (40 bytes, `len(IP()/TCP())` returns `40`).

You can save your capture (as PCAP, not PCAPNG) from Wireshark, and then load it in Scapy to decode it:

```
>>> x = rdpcap('your_capture.cap')
>>> PacketList(IP(str(p[TCP].payload)) for p in x
...            if TCP in p and p[IP].len >= 80).show()
```

If you want to control the TCP options with Scapy, then you have to create the packets and send them with `sr()` (but then you will have to open the connection by yourself).

Comment: Linux TCP stack sees the TCP packet created by scapy as a rogue packet and sends a RST packet. I used Ip tables to drop RST packets, I know that socket.getsocketopt() to find the value of congestion window but I dont know how to get Scapy connection's information . Hence, I used StreamSocket(). So, does it mean that my 'AE' TCP packet is just data payload of under lying TCP ('PA')? is that the reason why wireshark shows PA packets and not see 'EA' packets ??? In that case, I think I will start building packets using raw_sockets. Thank You.

Comment: Also, few other questions: what do you mean by 'open the connection by yourself?" . Do you mean I use scapy to do the TCP 3way handshake ? if yes- Is there a way in which I can get the socket parameters of this connection?  Secondly, is the encapsulation of IP()/TCP()/IP()/TCP() limited to the usage of StreamSocket() ? I ask this because when I trigger a standalone IP()/TCP(flags='AE') packet from scapy, I see wireshark caputring the packet as it is.  cntd...

Comment: ...cntd Third: Incase the scapy packet is indeed encapsulated , even then wireshark should show the packets as encapsulated. Sorry about the barge of questions. I am trying to wrap my head around how Scapy's StreamSocket() actually works.

Comment: As I mention, "On the network, and for Wireshark, the packet is only raw data transported over TCP". Wireshark has no way to guess that the payload of the first `IP()/TCP()` payload can be decoded as an IP packet. I'm updating the answer to add more about that.